# Importing Package-Private Classes to JShell

Tags: java, package, private, java-9, jshell

I was playing around with JShell after the Java 9 release, and I tried importing a package I made. As the entire application I'm coding it for will be contained in that package, every class but one (which I haven't coded yet) is package-private. My classpath is correct, but I still can't use any of the types declared in the package in JShell (it throws a "cannot find symbol" error). ***Do I need to make them public for them to be accessible, or is there some way I can test package-private classes***? Here's the exact code I tried.

My current directory is

```
C:\Users\Sylvaenn\OneDrive\Documents\Programs\Java\src
```

My class path is

```
C:\Users\Sylvaenn\OneDrive\Documents\Programs\Java\cls
```

and the package directory (for the bytecode) is

```
C:\Users\Sylvaenn\OneDrive\Documents\Programs\Java\cls\collatz
```

***`CollatzSequence` is a package-private class contained in `collatz`.***

```
PS C:\Users\Sylvaenn> cd OneDrive\Documents\Programs\Java\src
PS C:\Users\Sylvaenn\OneDrive\Documents\Programs\Java\src> jshell
|  Welcome to JShell -- Version 9
|  For an introduction type: /help intro

jshell> import collatz.*;

jshell> CollatzSequence seq = new CollatzSequence(BigInteger.ONE);
|  Error:
|  cannot find symbol
|    symbol:   class CollatzSequence
|  CollatzSequence seq = new CollatzSequence(BigInteger.ONE);
|  ^-------------^
|  Error:
|  cannot find symbol
|    symbol:   class CollatzSequence
|  CollatzSequence seq = new CollatzSequence(BigInteger.ONE);
|                            ^-------------^

jshell> /imports
|    import java.io.*
|    import java.math.*
|    import java.net.*
|    import java.nio.file.*
|    import java.util.*
|    import java.util.concurrent.*
|    import java.util.function.*
|    import java.util.prefs.*
|    import java.util.regex.*
|    import java.util.stream.*
|    import collatz.*

jshell>
```

Comment: Could you please share a reproducible code for the scenario? That would help make the question clear.

Comment: I just included it in my edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as i know (correct me if i am wrong), you cannot create a Class *in a specific package* using JShell (classes created within JShell are always in the default package).

That being said, you cannot access your package-private classes from within JShell. This is "normal" Java behaviour.

Comment: Regarding creating a class in a specific package, I couldn't find a way to do so with JShell commands, and it otherwise makes sense that you wouldn't be able to do so, but I don't know for sure. And I suppose not being able to access package-private classes makes sense as well, but it's a huge disappointment.

Answer (score 4):

From the JEP#220 - [The Java Shell (Read-Eval-Print Loop)](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/222)

> A snippet may not declare a package or a module. All JShell code is
>   placed in a single package in an unnamed module. The name of the
>   package is controlled by JShell.

That is the reason probably why you are not able to declare a `package` within JShell.

---

As the [tool documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/jshell/commands.htm#JSHEL-GUID-F4881B8E-8B6C-4906-A100-E78C4AFC277D) suggests though you can give this a try:-

> *The default startup script consists of several common imports. You can personalize your startup entries with the `/set` start command.*

where you can [set the classpath](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/jshell/external-code.htm#JSHEL-GUID-9FE683FB-C5F7-40C6-9609-34FAB56193C4) or [the modulepath](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/jshell/external-code.htm#JSHEL-GUID-BF9E7C33-27FE-4D9D-82BD-FDAC8DF1D527) of the class you would make use of :

```
jshell --class-path C:\Users\Sylvaenn\OneDrive\Documents\Programs\Java\cls
```

Comment: Very useful information, but I'm not trying to declare a new package; I'm trying to access package-private classes in an existing one. My class path already points to the correct directory, but I'll try explicitly setting it in the shell. However, I think the accepted answer is right; only public classes are accessible to JShell.